# Report Builder 3.0 downloaded in 2020 needs to target SSRS 2014

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I downloaded Report Builder in Aug 2020 (now).  I need to write reports for [SQL Server Reporting Services](https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=Wikipedia%20SQL%20reporting%20services) 2014. It wasn't till I attempted to deploy the first report that I remembered having trouble with incompatibility of schema versions.

I tried looking up and downloading something called at Microsoft, Report Builder 3 for [SQL Server 2014](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Microsoft_SQL_Server#SQL_Server_2014), but I got the same named Windows Installer file (MSI) as the recent one. Trying to install it in a different location resulted in a failed install; a DLL file failed.

Is there a way to get Report Builder to target the older SSRS 2014?  If not, what is the preferred way to write reports for SSRS 2014?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to download Visual Studio *Community Edition*. You can change the target server under by right-clicking report project and then select Targetserverversion.

See this Microsoft page for details:

*[Set Deployment Properties (Reporting Services)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tools/set-deployment-properties-reporting-services?view=sql-server-ver15)*